# signal Segmentation fault after specific url access

Tags: apache-2.2, php

In my PHP program when I access specific URL (POST some data) the request has been aborted and this logs appear in Apache error.log:

```
WARNING: HOME is not set, using root: /  
[Thu Sep 13 22:49:47 2012] [notice] child pid 32111 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

What's the problem?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/dev/debugging.html

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/configure-apache-web-server-for-core-dump.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a software problem (could be one of many, but almost certainly a programming error).

In order to figure it out you would need to run your web server inside of a debugger to locate the point in the code where the segfault is happening -- if your "server experience is weak" there is a very good chance that this sort of debugging will be out of your depth, and you should refer the problem to the person who wrote the code that is trying to handle this POST request.

Comment: Code is written by myself and work perfectly in my local Ubunto OS, but this server is Debian and I dont have access the person who configure it.What about "WARNING: HOME is not set, using root: /" ?Is there any suggestion for trying?

Comment: @realman That may or may not be related (If you don't see it in your development environment, figure out why you see it in production, and if it's a problem fix it. dmars gave you some tips.).  To be blunt, *YOU* need to debug this - Figure out what is different between Development and Production environments that is causing the problem, and you will be able to resolve it. With the information given that's almost impossible to do over the internet...

Answer (score 1):

HOME is not set means that the user under which the web server is running does not have a home directory defined (or maybe it doesn't exist).

If your code is the same on both local machine and the server, try comparing the data you POST. Check if:

- there is anything unusual in the data you sent
- there is a problem when you POST the same data